# most efficient client to client chat system

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, node.js

i am trying to build a one on one chat web application in php.

currently i am using a mysql database to hold messages as well but i recognize that this is very inefficient. i would like to have ONLY a user table with the ip address and some sort of script to allow each single client to directly connect to the user that clients wants to talk to. i am looking for someone who could point me into the right direction.

basically i do not want the server to take care of the messaging system but still letting the users sending private messages to each other and be able to switch between the various conversation tabs. i read a bit about node.js, but i am not quite sure it's the right thing?

if maybe you can show me some pseudocode or just simply point me into the right direction would be good.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You *must* store the content in the database...how else would the chats be updated?

Comment: _"some sort of script to allow each single client to directly connect to the user that clients wants to talk to...basically i do not want the server to take care of the messaging system"_ - You're saying you want the client PCs to communicate directly with each other _without_ going through your webserver?

Comment: @Purmou lies, there is no reason to store chats.

Comment: You want P2P software, that doesn't exist outside browser addons like opera unite

Comment: @Raynos: I know of no other way for two people to have a conversation and have live updates of the chat messages...

Comment: @Purmou pipes. You pipe data from client -> server -> file. There's no reason to store it in a database.

Comment: I'd use a combination of [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) and a db like redis or membase that write the information to memory and periodically flush the data to the filesystem.

Comment: take for example chatroulette, i dont think the webcam connection is handled by the server.... and i think the text sent as well. what do?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is impossible. There is no way to cause a browser to accept incoming connections using Javascript. (Nor would that even work reliably if there was, as most users nowadays are behind some variety of NAT or firewall.)

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is impossible, there always has to be a server in the middle. All chat systems are using a server.

Answer (score -1):

I know this isn't really answering your question, but why not use MSN Messenger or yahoo chat.

Comment: This is probably better off as a comment. You've already stated it's not an answer :)